# jQuery force html5 video to play "Picture in Picture" when "i" key is pressed

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can i use `jquery`(or javascript) to force an html5 `video` player to play in `picture in picture` mode?(image below)

[image: picture in picture].

This is for my personal site on which i'm using `jquery 3.3.1`(hosted by Google). For now i managed to use `space` bar to play/pause. This is my code so far:

```
<video id="player">
   <!-- source -->
</video>
<script>
player = $('#player')[0];

var player = $('#player')[0];
$(window).keydown(function(e) {
    switch(e.which){
        case(32):
            if(player.paused){
                player.play();
            } else{
                player.pause();
            }
        break; 
    }
});
</script>
```

Here is the code on [CodePen](https://codepen.io/emanuelones/pen/VqybQP).

The `i` key on `keydown` is `73`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is possible, although obviously [only in browsers which support PIP](https://caniuse.com/#feat=picture-in-picture) (at the time of this answer that's only Chrome 70 & 71).

To make it work listen for the <kbd>i</kbd> key in your `switch`. Then you can can call `requestPictureInPicture()` on the player to have it enter PIP mode. To make the toggle work when pressing <kbd>i</kbd> again you need to check the `pictureInPictureElement` property of the `document`. If it returns `true`, then PIP mode is already in use and you can end it by calling `document.exitPictureInPicture()`, like this:

```js
var player = $("#player")[0];

$(window).keydown(function(e) {
  switch (e.which) {
    case 32:
      player.paused ? player.play() : player.pause();
      break;
    case 73:
      if (player.requestPictureInPicture) { // feature detection to stop errors in unsupported browsers
        if (document.pictureInPictureElement) {
          document.exitPictureInPicture();
        } else {
          player.requestPictureInPicture();
        }
      }
      break;
  }
});
```

```css
video {
  width: 450px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<video id="player" controls>
  <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/rain.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

One caveat here is that after pressing <kbd>i</kbd> the focus is transferred to the PIP window, hence pressing <kbd>i</kbd> a second time appears to do nothing until you click on the browser window again to return focus so that the `keydown` listener can take effect.

Comment: If I may ask, where did you find this? Any sources?

Comment: I found it in the Chrome dev blog: https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/09/picture-in-picture.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan - one more question, it works perfectly but after i press `i` and it goes in PIP mode i have to click back inside the window before being able to press `i` again to exit PIP. Is there a way to keep the focus on the window? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Yeah I noticed that myself an added a note to the answer about it. It may be possible to return focus back to the document with a timeout. Let me try.

Comment: @EmanuelOnes it appears it's not possible to return the focus to the original window as the PIP player runs as a separate instance, therefore calling `focus()` in a timer has no effect.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan, do you mind if I ask if there's now any solution to this? I'm doing the same thing.